# PHP Count No of hotels located in each city

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a count of No of hotels located in each city.

I have 2 tables for the same. First table is hotel_master

```
 hotel_master
 id | hotel_name | city_code
```

Second table is city_master

```
 city_master
 id | city_code | city_name
```

Is it possible to get the count from a query?

To start with it i have tried this query or i need to use a do while loop?

```
 SELECT
 hotel_master.hotel_name,
 city_master.city_name
 FROM hotel_master
 INNER JOIN city_master ON hotel_master.city_code = city_master.city_code
```

Pls help me on the same.

Comment: "Is it possible to get the count from a query?"... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html . What have you researched or tried so far? This is not a complex thing to go and find out or try for yourself. Also you may like to read http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(h.city_code) as total_hotel, c.city_name
FROM hotel_master h
INNER JOIN city_master c ON h.city_code = c.city_code
GROUP BY h.city_code
```

Use `COUNT` on the field from `hotel_master`. It will get the number of hotel based on city.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM hotel_master 
  JOIN city_master 
    ON hotel_master.city_code = city_master.city_code 
  GROUP 
    BY hotel_master.city_code
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` will do it

```
SELECT
  count(hotel_master.hotel_name),
  city_master.city_name
FROM hotel_master
INNER JOIN city_master ON hotel_master.city_code = city_master.city_code
GROUP BY city_master.city_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to use `GROUP BY` clause in query to get hotel count in every city.

```
SELECT city_master.city_name, count(hotel_master.id) hotetcount 
  FROM hotel_master 
  JOIN city_master 
    ON hotel_master.city_code = city_master.city_code 
  GROUP 
    BY city_master.city_code
```